# lpoptions: unable to set instances

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, printing, cups, lp

I have installed a network printer and would like to setup instances. To do so, the commands I used are:

```
lpoptions -p my_printer/a3booklet -o PagePolicy=On -o PageSize=A3 -o PageRegion=A4 -o MediaType=Plain -o OutputBin=None -o KCStaple=Center -o StapleCount=None -o KCPunch=None -o KCBooklet=Left -o KCFold=On -o Duplex=DuplexTumble
 
lpoptions -p my_printer/a4simplex -o PagePolicy=None -o PageSize=A4 -o PageRegion=A4 -o MediaType=Plain -o OutputBin=FDStackerA -o KCStaple=None -o StapleCount=None -o KCPunch=None -o KCBooklet=None -o KCFold=None -o Duplex=None
```

After executing the command, there is no error. However, the instances are not listed (checked using `lpstat`). The options mentioned above are correct.

I am currently using Ubuntu 200.4. For the records, I was using the same commands (same scripts) on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 without any problem.

Is there any change in the new version of Ubuntu/CUPS or am I missing something?